# TypeError: auc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reorder'

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, auc

Kindly let me know why this error is coming?

```
def roc_aupr_score(y_true, y_score, average="macro"):
    def _binary_roc_aupr_score(y_true, y_score):
        precision, recall, pr_thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_score)
        return auc(recall, precision, reorder=True)
```

```
File "DDIMDL.py", line 387, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "DDIMDL.py", line 367, in main
    all_result, each_result = cross_validation(all_matrix, new_label, clf, event_num, seed, CV,
  File "DDIMDL.py", line 190, in cross_validation
    result_all, result_eve = evaluate(y_pred, y_score, y_true, event_num, set_name)
  File "DDIMDL.py", line 214, in evaluate
    result_all[1] = roc_aupr_score(y_one_hot, pred_score, average='micro')
  File "DDIMDL.py", line 301, in roc_aupr_score
    return _average_binary_score(_binary_roc_aupr_score, y_true, y_score, average)
  File "DDIMDL.py", line 298, in _average_binary_score
    score[c] = binary_metric(y_true_c, y_score_c)
  File "DDIMDL.py", line 281, in _binary_roc_aupr_score
    return auc(recall, precision, reorder=True)
TypeError: auc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reorder'
```

how can i correct it

kindly let me know how can solve the issue.

Comment: I think it's deprecated. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html

Comment: Then how can I solve the error?

Comment: From the older docs (https://scikit-learn.org/0.21/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html) says that orders it by `recall`. You'd have to order it manually. Try `recall.sort()` before you return `uac`.

Comment: return auc(recall, precision, reorder=False) (is this ok?)

Comment: No, you can't use `reorder` parameter anymore. Since there's two metrics that have to be sorted, I can't anything for sure without seeing them. Could you include `print(recall)` and `print(precision)` outputs to the question?

Comment: https://github.com/YifanDengWHU/DDIMDL/blob/master/DDIMDL.py , its code link which i am using, pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, `reorder` parameter has been deprecated in version `0.20` and removed in `0.22`

```
def roc_aupr_score(y_true, y_score, average="macro"):
    def _binary_roc_aupr_score(y_true, y_score):
        precision, recall, pr_thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_score)
        return auc(recall, precision)
```

Should work as intented. If not, you can sort `precision` and `recall` like this:

```
precision, recall, pr_thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_score)
new_order = np.lexsort([recall, precision])
recall = recall[new_order]
precision = precision[new_order]
print(recall , precision )
return auc(recall, precision)
```

Comment: now this error is coming -  anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1272: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is il
l-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))